# Cannot get PubSub emulator to run in Docker using docker-compose

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-pubsub-emulator

I am trying to get PubSub emulator to run in a docker-compose project but I keep getting the error:

```
auth-service_1  | Error: Unable to detect a Project Id in the current environment. 
auth-service_1  | To learn more about authentication and Google APIs, visit: 
auth-service_1  | https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
auth-service_1  |     at /app/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:84:31
auth-service_1  |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

I have added every environment variable that I could find on numerous GitHub issues threads but nothing seems to help.

Here is the docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  pubsub:
    image: andrewrjones/google-pubsub-emulator:latest
    environment:
      - PUBSUB_PROJECT_ID=project-test
      - PUBSUB_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8042
      - PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST="localhost:8042"
      - GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT="api-xx-dev"
      - PUBSUB_PROJECT_ID="api-xx-dev"
      - PROJECT_ID="api-xx-dev"
      - GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/serviceAccount.json"
      - GCLOUD_PROJECT="api-xx-dev"
  ports:
    - "8042:8042"
  networks:
    - main

auth-service:
  build: ./auth
  volumes:
    - ./auth:/app
  ports:
    - 4000:8080
  networks:
    - main

user-service:
  build: ./user
  volumes:
    - ./user:/app
  ports:
    - 4001:8081
  networks:
    - main

networks:
  main:
```

Route calling PubSub:

```
import express = require("express");
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import admin from "firebase-admin";
const { PubSub } = require("@google-cloud/pubsub");

const serviceAccount = require("../serviceAccount.json");

admin.initializeApp({
credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});

const router = express.Router();

const pubsub = new PubSub();

const publishTopic = async (user: any, topic: any) => {
try {
    const buffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(user));
    return await pubsub.topic(topic).publish(buffer);
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
};

router.post(
"/api/v2/create-user",
async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    const newUser = await admin.auth().createUser({ email, password });

    await publishTopic(newUser, "NEW_FIREBASE_USER_CREATED");

    res.send(newUser);
    } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(409).send({ errors: [{ message: error.message }] });
    }
}
);

export { router as createUserRouter };
```

I recall that I had to log into google via the cli to get this error to go on my local machine.

Comment: did you try `PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST="0.0.0.0:8042"` ?

Comment: Thanks. I tried this out but didn't help. The issue seems to be the "Unable to detect a Project Id"

Comment: that's an applicative issue, something with the code in your auth-service, can you add the relevant snippet?

Comment: Added above. Thanks

Comment: Did you run env-init and the rest of the steps here?
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator#manually_setting_the_variables

Comment: You probably need to set the PUBSUB_PROJECT_ID field. See details at the link in my previous comment.

Comment: The issue could have been because of the library version. Updating it to the current version should work if the problem is happening.